# Using TinyButStrong, how to get results to load into option tags?

Tags: php, mysql, tinybutstrong

Environment: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19

I'm new to using TinyButStrong.

Got results back from MYSQL stored Procedure, data looks like this:

```
vardump($auth_user_list); 
//example of output
array(10)
{ 
  [0]=> array(2) 
  { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["login"]=> string(5) "User1" 
  } 
  [1]=> array(2) 
  { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["login"]=> string(5) "User2" 
  }
...
 }
```

Using TinyButStrong I merge the results

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('auth_user_list',$auth_user_list);
```

On the loading page:

```
<select id="user_list" name="user_list" onchange="$('#username').val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)">
      <option>Select user<option>    
      <option>[var.auth_user_list.login; block=opt]</option>                                
 </select>
```

The options in the results are not loading in my select list. What am I doing incorrectly - I have followed the templates.

I also get this notice since I have my error_reporting set to E_ALL that

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Landells\classes\tbs_class_php5.php on line 1253
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are merging a block named `auth_user_list`, your template should be:

```
<option>[auth_user_list.login;block=option]</option>
```

`var` is a prefix for merging tags embedded in some parameters such as if/then/else/script/...
In older TBS version it was also used to merge automatic fields, but not blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I never referenced the block correctly.

It should be:

```
<option>[var.auth_user_list.login; block=option]</option>
```